# Get thumbnail of the image selected from Gallery

Tags: android, android-gallery

I tried this code snippet :

```
   if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA) {
            photoUri = capturedImagePath();
            Log.d("path to captured image", capturedImagePath().toString());
            Bitmap aBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoUri.toString());
            mProfilePic.setImageBitmap(aBitmap);
            mEncodedImageString = convertBitmapToString(aBitmap);
        Log.v("Base64 Image String : ", mEncodedImageString);

    } else if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE) {
        photoUri = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = {
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA
        };
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(photoUri, filePathColumn, null, null,
                null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();
        Bitmap aBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
        mProfilePic.setImageBitmap(aBitmap);
        mEncodedImageString = convertBitmapToString(aBitmap);
        Log.v("Base64 Image String : ", mEncodedImageString);
    }
}
```

to get the image path but it gives me the original image. What I want is the thumbnail of the image selected. Can anyone please help me to achieve the same?

Comment: Do these images have thumbnails? If not then you will need to create them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily create a thumbnail like this:

```
int thumbFactor = 4; // choose a power of 2
Bitmap thumb = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, image.getWidth()/thumbFactor, image.getHeight()/thumbFactor, false);
```

See [Bitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html)

Answer (score 1):

Actually you cannot get thumbnail by URI query. Because Gallery caches thumbnail by itself. If you need thumbnail, you have to decode the original image by yourself.